# "Restart denied, cycling is disabled" Heroku error when trying to restart dyno in Heroku pipeline

Tags: heroku, restart

Has anyone come across this before? The error message doesn't provide much useful information and Googling the error messsage returns no results. My app is part of a Pipeline, I think that might have something to do with it.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 7):

Based on the time of this post, heroku is having issues with recycling dynos.

[image: heroku status]

Answer (score 1):

Happening again today - heroku seems to be down (4th of Feb, 2020).

For more info: https://status.heroku.com/

[image]